# Social Engine Zend Framework - Dynamic Ajax dropdown for Country / State / City

Tags: php, ajax, model-view-controller, zend-framework, smarty

I am working with Social Engine which is based on Zend Framework and Smarty Templates.

I need to make custom functionality for profile page, where I need Ajax based Dynamic Country / State / City selections like

Dropdown for Country -> on selection of some country, State will display belonging to selected country and State selection -> related Cities will display. I have separate tables for my country/state and city.

Anybody can help us or can provide some reference / examples for the same?

I don't know, how to make Ajax calls and render my views with this !

Regards !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See code below:

giving code from my project loads  segment, sub-segments of ship type. same as country ,state

first make parent drop down as usual like this :

```
 <?php 

  echo $this->formSelect('segment','none',array('class' => 'select-advanced', 'width' => '250'),$this->arrInput['shiptype']);  

?>
```

here arrInput['shiptype'] is from controllar

make a div for child drop down on ur form

Now put below jquery code on ur form:

```
<script>

var base_path = "<?php echo $this->baseUrl();?>/";

$('#segnam').change(function()
{

var segId=document.getElementById('segment').value;

      $.ajax({
                 url:  base_path + "search/subseg/",
                data: "segId="+segId,
                type: 'GET',
             success: function (resp) { document.getElementById('subsegdiv').innerHTML=resp;},
               error: function(e){  alert('Error: '+e);  }  
            });
});
</script>
```

now for child drop dowm in yor controllar make a action :

```
public function subsegAction()
    {   
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $objShiptype = new Shiptype();   
         $segId=$request->getParam('segId');  
        $SubSegArr=$objShiptype->getSubSegment($segId);
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
            $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
            $this->view->subseg=$SubSegArr;

    }
```

now make a view for above action:

make html drop down (child)  using html take data from subseg controller

here refer segment = country
subseg = state

for city follow same make a action and view and jquery code again.

If not clear u are free to ask. I have donw this task. It's tricky :)